# Intel Wireless 8260 not detected by Ubuntu 19.04 on Dell E7450 Laptop

Tags: wireless, 19.04

Problem # Not able to detect Wifi Adapter – Intel 8260 – Ubuntu 19.04

Hardware #

Laptop Dell Latitude E7450 – BIOS version 21 – Service Tag # 789YD72
4GB + 4GB = 8 GB  DDR3L
Core i7 5600U @ 2.6 Ghz – Processor id 306d4
Wifi # Intel Wireless 8260NGW

Notes #

1. Aeroplane Mode disabled using Dell Hardware keys – Fn + PrtScr.

https://ibb.co/6wPY0N3

2. rfkill list

   sysadmin@AMMZ-LT-E7450-001: $ rfkill list
       0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
           Soft-blocked: no
           Hard blocked: no
3. sudo dmidecode | grep -i version

https://ibb.co/Bn5qw2r

```
Version: A21
    Version: Not Specified
    Version:    
    Version: Not Specified
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Name: Firmware Version Info
    SBDS Version: 1.0
```

4. sudo dmidecode | grep -i dell

https://ibb.co/dQ15T46

```
Vendor: Dell Inc.
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    String 1: Dell System
    String 4: 12[www.dell.com]
    Name: DELL 5K1GW57
        DELL
```

5. sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/dell.conf <<< "blacklist dell_laptop"

https://ibb.co/qs6DXq6

```
blacklist dell_laptop
```

6. sudo modprobe iwlwifi
   dmesg | grep iwl

https://ibb.co/82Rvn5v

https://ibb.co/FVqwDVD

```
[    3.030949] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.048420] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.9f0a2d68.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.090015] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    5.173958] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending NVM_ACCESS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
[    5.173962] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 0 write_ptr 1
[    5.174220] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[    5.174239] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.174242] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000100, count: 6
[    5.174244] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.9f0a2d68.0
[    5.174246] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[    5.174248] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    5.174250] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    5.174252] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00012526 | branchlink2
[    5.174253] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0001C2B6 | interruptlink1
[    5.174255] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000136AA | interruptlink2
[    5.174257] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[    5.174259] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[    5.174261] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[    5.174262] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    5.174264] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x001EBBCE | tsf low
[    5.174266] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    5.174268] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    5.174269] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x001EBBCF | time gp2
[    5.174271] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000009 | uCode revision type
[    5.174273] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000024 | uCode version major
[    5.174275] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x9F0A2D68 | uCode version minor
[    5.174276] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000201 | hw version
[    5.174278] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00489008 | board version
[    5.174280] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[    5.174281] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00022080 | isr0
[    5.174282] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    5.174284] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x08001802 | isr2
[    5.174286] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x004000C0 | isr3
[    5.174287] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    5.174288] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    5.174290] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[    5.174292] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00006B98 | l2p_control
[    5.174293] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    5.174295] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    5.174296] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    5.174298] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000F | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    5.174300] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x04120134 | timestamp
[    5.174301] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00340008 | flow_handler
[    5.174441] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    5.174443] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    5.174445] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink2
[    5.174446] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    5.174448] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    5.174449] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data1
[    5.174451] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data2
[    5.174453] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[    5.174455] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac major
[    5.174456] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac minor
[    5.174458] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | frame pointer
[    5.174460] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | stack pointer
[    5.174461] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    5.174463] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    5.174467] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: OTP is blank
[    5.174470] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Can't parse empty family 8000 OTP/NVM sections
[    5.174472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to read NVM: -61
[    5.192190] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -61
```

7. Explorer view of lib/firmware

https://ibb.co/fFYWQgn

8. (

Reading database ... 208667 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.3.1-050301_5.3.1-050301.201909210632_all.deb ... Unpacking linux-headers-5.3.1-050301 (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) over (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.3.1-050301-generic_5.3.1-050301.201909210632_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-headers-5.3.1-050301-generic (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) over (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-5.3.1-050301-generic_5.3.1-050301.201909210632_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.3.1-050301-generic (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) over (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.3.1-050301-generic_5.3.1-050301.201909210632_amd64.deb ... Unpacking linux-modules-5.3.1-050301-generic (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) over (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Setting up linux-headers-5.3.1-050301 (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Setting up linux-headers-5.3.1-050301-generic (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Setting up linux-modules-5.3.1-050301-generic (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.3.1-050301-generic (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.3.1-050301-generic (5.3.1-050301.201909210632) ... /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools: update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.1-050301-generic I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-1 I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1) I: Set the RESUME variable to override this. /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub: Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub' Sourcing file`/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg' Generating grub configuration file ... Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.1-050301-generic Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.1-050301-generic Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-29-generic Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-29-generic Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration done

9. [Copied Location Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fV5T.png)

Please Help. Thanks!

10. @K7AAY - still the same.

11.

```
1a98-INTEL-EDK2-2-tplg.bin  ctfw-3.2.1.1.bin             isci                     iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode             libertas                       ql2200_fw.bin             tehuti
3com                        ctfw-3.2.3.0.bin             iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode     iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode             liquidio                       ql2300_fw.bin             ti_3410.fw
a300_pfp.fw                 ctfw-3.2.5.1.bin             iwlwifi-100-5.ucode      iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode             matrox                         ql2322_fw.bin             ti_5052.fw
a300_pm4.fw                 ctspeq.bin                   iwlwifi-105-6.ucode      iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode             mediatek                       ql2400_fw.bin             ti-connectivity
acenic                      cxgb3                        iwlwifi-135-6.ucode      iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode             mellanox                       ql2500_fw.bin             tigon
adaptec                     cxgb4                        iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode     iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode             microchip                      qlogic                    ti-keystone
advansys                    dpaa2                        iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode     iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode             moxa                           r128                      tlg2300_firmware.bin
agere_ap_fw.bin             dsp56k                       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode    iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode             mrvl                           r8a779x_usb3_v1.dlmem     ttusb-budget
agere_sta_fw.bin            dvb-fe-xc4000-1.4.1.fw       iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode    iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode             mt7601u.bin                    r8a779x_usb3_v2.dlmem     ueagle-atm
amd                         dvb-fe-xc5000-1.6.114.fw     iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode    iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode             mt7650.bin                     r8a779x_usb3_v3.dlmem     usbdux
amdgpu                      dvb-fe-xc5000c-4.1.30.7.fw   iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode    iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode             mt7662.bin                     radeon                    usbduxfast_firmware.bin
amd-ucode                   dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw      iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode    iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode             mt7662_rom_patch.bin           README                    usbdux_firmware.bin
ar3k                        dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw         iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode     iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode             mts_cdma.fw                    regulatory.db             usbduxsigma_firmware.bin
ar5523.bin                  dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw         iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode     iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode             mts_edge.fw                    regulatory.db.p7s         v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw
as102_data1_st.hex          dvb-usb-terratec-h5-drxk.fw  iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode     iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode             mts_gsm.fw                     rockchip                  v4l-cx23418-apu.fw
as102_data2_st.hex          e100                         iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode    iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode             mts_mt9234mu.fw                rp2.fw                    v4l-cx23418-cpu.fw
asihpi                      ea                           iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode    iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode              mts_mt9234zba.fw               rsi                       v4l-cx23418-dig.fw
ath10k                      edgeport                     iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode    iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode              mwl8k                          rsi_91x.fw                v4l-cx2341x-dec.fw
ath3k-1.fw                  emi26                        iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode    iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode              mwlwifi                        rt2561.bin                v4l-cx2341x-enc.fw
ath6k                       emi62                        iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode     iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode              myri10ge_eth_big_z8e.dat       rt2561s.bin               v4l-cx2341x-init.mpg
ath9k_htc                   ene-ub6250                   iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode     iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode              myri10ge_ethp_big_z8e.dat      rt2661.bin                v4l-cx23885-avcore-01.fw
atmel                       ess                          iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode     iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode              myri10ge_ethp_z8e.dat          rt2860.bin                v4l-cx25840.fw
atmel_at76c504_2958.bin     f2255usb.bin                 iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode     iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode  myri10ge_eth_z8e.dat           rt2870.bin                v4l-pvrusb2-24xxx-01.fw
atmel_at76c504a_2958.bin    go7007                       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode     iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode  myri10ge_rss_eth_big_z8e.dat   rt3070.bin                v4l-pvrusb2-29xxx-01.fw
atmsar11.fw                 hfi1_dc8051.fw               iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode  myri10ge_rss_ethp_big_z8e.dat  rt3090.bin                vicam
atusb                       hfi1_fabric.fw               iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode  myri10ge_rss_ethp_z8e.dat      rt3290.bin                vntwusb.fw
av7110                      hfi1_pcie.fw                 iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode  myri10ge_rss_eth_z8e.dat       rt73.bin                  vpu_d.bin
bnx2                        hfi1_sbus.fw                 iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode     iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode  netronome                      RTL8192E                  vpu_p.bin
bnx2x                       hp                           iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode    iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode  NPE-B                          rtl_bt                    vxge
brcm                        htc_7010.fw                  iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode    iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode  NPE-C                          rtl_nic                   WHENCE.ubuntu
cadence                     htc_9271.fw                  iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode    iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode  nvidia                         rtlwifi                   whiteheat.fw
carl9170-1.fw               i2400m-fw-usb-1.4.sbcf       iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode    iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode  ositech                        rtw88                     whiteheat_loader.fw
carl9170fw                  i2400m-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode    iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode       phanfw.bin                     s2250.fw                  wil6210.brd
cavium                      i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf        iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode     iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode       qat_895xcc.bin                 s2250_loader.fw           wil6210.fw
cbfw-3.2.1.1.bin            i915                         iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode     iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode       qat_895xcc_mmp.bin             s5p-mfc.fw                wsm_22.bin
cbfw-3.2.3.0.bin            imx                          iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode     iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode       qat_c3xxx.bin                  s5p-mfc-v6.fw             yam
cbfw-3.2.5.1.bin            intel                        iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode    iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode      qat_c3xxx_mmp.bin              s5p-mfc-v6-v2.fw          yamaha
cis                         intel-ucode                  iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode    iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode      qat_c62x.bin                   s5p-mfc-v7.fw             zd1201-ap.fw
configure                   ipw2100-1.3.fw               iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode    kaweth                             qat_c62x_mmp.bin               s5p-mfc-v8.fw             zd1201.fw
cpia2                       ipw2100-1.3-i.fw             iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode    keyspan                            qat_mmp.bin                    sb16                      zd1211
ct2fw-3.2.1.1.bin           ipw2100-1.3-p.fw             iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode    keyspan_pda                        qca                            scripts
ct2fw-3.2.3.0.bin           ipw2200-bss.fw               iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode     korg                               qcom                           sdd_sagrad_1091_1098.bin
ct2fw-3.2.5.1.bin           ipw2200-ibss.fw              iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode     lbtf_usb.bin                       qed                            slicoss
ctefx.bin                   ipw2200-sniffer.fw           iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode   lgs8g75.fw                         ql2100_fw.bin
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99301/discussion-on-question-by-a-m-m-zulfiquar-intel-wireless-8260-not-detected-by-ub).

Answer (score 1):

There are some bugs right now even in the latest stable kernel in Arch Linux regarding the Intel wireless 8260. I have kernel 5.3.1 and Intel 8260 in Lenovo Yoga 710 and I am getting errors like this.

> Microcode SW error detected
>   FW error in SYNC CMD GEO_TX_POWER_LIMIT

Like I said I have the latest of everything but just about a week a firmware update came out along with the new kernel so I guess it got messed up then. If anyone has any thoughts or help please don't hesitate to chime in.

Comment: 1....Which means till you updated to 5.3.1, was it working?
2. Which kernel were you using prior to 5.3.1, where in 8260 was working?